# How should I contain mold contaminated items?

Tags: bathroom, mold, water-damage

I previously asked this question
[Is this mold or some other substance?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198374/is-this-mold-or-some-other-substance)
where I discovered some mold behind a bathroom panel.  The sensible thing to do would be to just throw the mold contaminated parts away and replace them.  However I put the panel back in because I needed to hold onto the mold for certain reasons and I'm trying to come up with something better than putting it back into place or leaving it out which would be even more hazardous.

I'm thinking I could

1. cover the effected parts with foil, tape then put back in to place.
2. Alternatively I could cut the affected parts off and put it into a sealed plastic container.  If so what can I use to do the cutting to make the least amount of mess?  Im not sure what material it is.

Any idea on what might be the best way to approach this?  I don't have a private balcony or anything where I could simply store the items in the mean time.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are affected by mold etc, then you should have replaced all contaminated materials not just put them back. Why would you think you need to keep the mold? Especially as you say it affects you.

Comment: @SolarMike I believe the OP is involved in a bit of a battle with his landlord and may need evidence.

Comment: @Freeman if you check out many of the OP's posts they are all about suffering from smells and you can also look at posts on Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair. So I don't think it is a landlord issue.

Comment: @SolarMike I recalled that. I thought I also recalled something about being in a rental property. Maybe my recaller hasn't been caffeinated enough yet this morning... If it's not a rental, trash 'em, but he says he's got reasons for keeping them, so... keep 'em it is.

Answer (score -1):

Covering with foil will not help. Use some 3% hydrogen peroxide on it and it will kill the surface mold , putting in plastic will accelerate the mold / fungi growth.
To answer in part from your previous question , not all mold is harmful to humans and our pets, of the many thousands of mold species only a few hundred are harmful , more are beneficial.
I regularly use hydrogen peroxide for cleaning and sanitation of wood.  Carpets , concrete. 3% like you get in the grocery store sponged on will kill the mold but to prevent it from returning your area needs to stay dry.

There is no problem in continuing to use that panel.
I would sponge hydrogen peroxide water mix on and after it drys put it back in place 3% or stronger.
I would also treat the area close to where that was it won’t hurt anything and you do not need to rinse.

I purchase stronger hydrogen peroxide 30+% it is a really good cleaner and at stronger concentrations +7% it will bleach / turn white material, hair etc
And it doesn’t stink like bleach. Remember to always add acid when diluting with water AAA ,

Comment: He's not looking to clean it, he's looking to store it for some unspecified, later use.

Comment: The cleaning would be the same in either case and putting in a plastic bag would be the worst option I covered that and foil really won’t do much so since in needs to be cleaned why not use it? But my answer specifically answered his 2 questions about storage thanks for the down vote

Comment: @EdBeal Why do you say foil will not help.  Foil is impermeable including to mold as far as I'm aware so should not let gasses out. Thanks.

Comment: I would agree if you have a large enough piece of foil to encapsulate the piece but again sealing a damp piece of fiber material with mold will just accelerate the decomposing as the mold / fungus eats it way.

Comment: @EdBeal doesn't the growth only happen if there is a moisture source?  If you foil wrap it and its not wet inside shouldn't be growing right?  Same with plastic container?  Thanks.

Comment: The moisture is already there , until that is totally dry the mold will be active. A plastic container acts like a hot house for plants maintains the humidity.