# Does the mold on this bathroom panel look like it can be washed off?

Tags: bathroom, mold, water-damage

[image] I previously asked this question
[Is this mold or some other substance?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198374/is-this-mold-or-some-other-substance)

Anybody know what material the bathrooom side panel is and does it look like the moldor whatever substances can simply be washed off or does the affected area/whole part need to be removed\replaced?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: People might be more inclined to answer if they could see the pics without having to click through to a different answer. The link is fine for the background, but this should be answerable by itself. Though it's borderline opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That panel is made of hardboard.

A cheap compressed fibre board that is often used for covering or closing areas which may need later access. Usually about 4 to 5mm thick and is often nailed, screwed or glued to a frame.

Given the porous nature of the board, then the best course of action is to replace it.

Comment: @Kris see edit.

Comment: If I cut the affected area off, could the rest of the board still be used as part of a temporary cover or would that too need to go?  thanks.

Comment: It is likely not in your best interests to attempt to continue using that board. It will not fit and cover well after cutting, and the moisture damage and fungus likely extend beyond what's visible. Like @SolarMike said, these panels are very cheap to replace.

Comment: @JamesWilson Yes, you can just "put it back" for a couple of days until you get around to replacing it, but I'd make it a priority for this weekend...or as soon as you can. It's been in that condition for a while, so a week or so longer isn't going to "break the world" but it ultimately needs replaced sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't really "wash off" mold or mildew. There are structures similar to roots that run through the materials that it grows on and even if you get the visible parts cleaned off, the remaining parts will still be there.

This panel is shot. The mold/mildew, water stains, and water damage have taken their toll. You'll spend more in time and money cleaning it up than to just buy new material and replace it.